# SQLite3 — NOT NULL applied to multiple columns

Tags: sqlite, constraints

In defining a SQLite3 table, the `NOT NULL` constraint can be applied to a single column:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    field1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    field2 INTEGER
);
```

Is there a way to apply the `NOT NULL` constraint not to a single column but to a set of two or more columns, so that at least one of those columns must not be null but any or all of the others may be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE TABLE tablename 
(
    field1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    field2 INTEGER,
    field3 INTEGER,
    CHECK (field2 is not null or field3 is not null)
);
```